# writing escape character to CSS style using SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to set the content property to "\e000", but no matter what I do it changes the value when compiling.

```
&-#{$iconName}::before {
    $code: #{"\\e" + $unicode};

    content: "" + $code;
}
```

Result:

```
.creator-icon.devicon-git::before {
content: "\\e602"; }

&-#{$iconName}::before {
    $code: #{"\e" + $unicode};

    content: "" + $code;
}
```

Result:

```
.creator-icon.devicon-git::before {
content: "602"; }

&-#{$iconName}::before {
    $code: "\e#{$unicode}";

    content: "" + $code;
}
```

Result:

```
.creator-icon.devicon-git::before {
content: ""; }
```

I want:

```
.creator-icon.devicon-git::before {
content: "\e602"; }
```

Will "\\e602" also work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try unquoting the string

```css
@function get-unicode($code) {
  @return unquote("\"\\e#{$code}\"");
}


&-#{$iconName}::before {
  content: get-unicode(602);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to sol:

```
&-#{$iconName}::before {
    content: unquote("\"\\e#{$unicode}\"");
}
```

Result:

```
.creator-icon.devicon-git::before {
content: "\e602"; }
```